# Swift 2.0 spritekit application crash, EXC_BAD_ACCESS, with no traceback to the relevant line

Tags: macos, swift, sprite-kit

EDIT: new description after transitioning to swift 2.0.

I'm working with an existing Swift 2.0 app on OSX 10.10, built with XCode 7.1. It's an interactive kiosk application running on a Mac Mini - a spritekit app that is doing some lower-level serial comms to accept input from a button and a few potentiometers (though that aspect is not causing any issues).

I've had issues with random crashing in deployment that never showed up in development or testing, often 6-8 hours into run time. I've gone back and more carefully unwrapped all optionals, which has helped the stability somewhat. But I am still getting daily crashes of this application.

Below is the latest symbolicated crash log:

```
Time Awake Since Boot: 7100 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000007c

VM Regions Near 0x7c:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100fee000-000000010100e000 [  128K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Documents/Volcano13.app/Contents/MacOS/Volcano

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.SpriteKit             0x000000010109fbe3 SKCSprite::removeSubsprite(SKCSprite*) + 131
1   com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00000001010a962d SKCEmitterSprite::~SKCEmitterSprite() + 79
2   com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00000001010a9224 SKCEmitterSprite::~SKCEmitterSprite() + 14
3   com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00000001010cdec6 -[SKNode dealloc] + 34
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff85f8b89c objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 236
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff897d5db0 CFRelease + 304
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff897ea39d -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 205
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff85f8b89c objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 236
8   com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00000001010ce024 -[SKNode .cxx_destruct] + 179
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff85f76ae8 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 127
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff85f71637 objc_destructInstance + 119
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff85f71595 object_dispose + 22
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff908f1cec -[NSResponder dealloc] + 139
13  com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00000001010cdee5 -[SKNode dealloc] + 65
14  com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00000001010be1b2 -[SKEffectNode dealloc] + 99
15  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff85f8b89c objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 236
16  com.apple.SpriteKit             0x0000000101069d52 -[SKView renderCallback:shouldBlock:] + 635
17  com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00000001010675ff __29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 56
18  com.apple.SpriteKit             0x00000001010befbf __39-[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:]_block_invoke33 + 32
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff86e79c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff86e8704e _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 412
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff86e79c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff86e85cbf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 861
23  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff898743f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
24  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8982f68f __CFRunLoopRun + 2159
25  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8982ebd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
26  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8c67956f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
27  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8c6792ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
28  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8c67912b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff908fd8ab _DPSNextEvent + 978
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff908fce58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff908f2af3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9086f244 NSApplicationMain + 1832
33  cmnh.Volcano                    0x00000001010092b9 main (in Volcano) (AppDelegate.swift:23)
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8dd315c9 start + 1
```

This seems to me to indicate a problem with removing an SKEmitter sprite after one of my scenes ended, but does not point me to anything more specific than that.

I do have two SKEmitter sprites that I added using the scene editor in XCode, both stationary with no target nodes. I pause and unpause them within my scene controller, but otherwise do no other operations with them. In fact, I am not adding or removing any nodes within the controller - everything that I need in the scene is the same as what is contained in the scene's SKS file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a really good reason why you can't update to Swift 2.0?

Comment: Limited time to work on this project, for the most part. And it isn't clear to me that converting to Swift 2.0 would address the issue that I'm seeing here.

Comment: Okay, it's not "clear" to me either. But this is exactly the kind of bug that Swift 2.0 _does_ fix, so you've only yourself to blame if you don't try it.

Comment: I took the time to run the migration utility, and updated the title and description. This now seems to be a spritekit issue.

Comment: Thanks for the report, and sorry that updating did not magically fix everything. :( At least you now have a completely different issue; that's good! This now appears to be a memory management issue; you can get a better idea what's going by turning on Zombies, perhaps.

Comment: Oh, one more thing - distinguish different optimization levels of your release build, as they may behave differently. Does the same crash happen with Optimization set to None and with Optimization set to Whole Module Optimization, for example?

Comment: I think Xcode 6.4 does not compile Swift 2.0?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update that detail. I'm using XCode 7.1

Comment: Also, I'll experiment with the optimization level next. 
Though I'm still not seeing any crashes in testing, so I'll have to continue testing for crashes in production I suppose.